# JavaScript webkit syntax error, work fine in Firefox; value vs. reference

Tags: javascript

I'm going through a collection of DOM elements, and when criteria is found, DOM element gets a CSS class `flashMe` added to it.

CSS is a 1 second animation - I'm then using a setTimeout to remove the CSS class 1.5 seconds later.

If I use function (varCounter) in the loop, it will use varCounter reference, not value.
So I'm using function (passedIndex = varCounter) which passes a current value, and works great in Firefox.

In WebKit (Chrome & Safari) same code throws: **SyntaxError: Expected token ')'** on 6th line: `function(pIndex=b)`

```
var self=this;
for(var b=0;b<this.someDOMcollection.length;b++){
    if(this.someDOMcollection[b].id==someCriteria){
        this.someDOMcollection[b].classList.add('flashMe');
        setTimeout(
            function(pIndex=b){
                self.someDOMcollection[pIndex].classList.remove('flashMe');
            }
        ,1500);//end Timeout
        break;
    }//if
}//b
```

One way to get around it is to make a separate function, and pass it currently found index value, but ideally I would like to keep it within the same block.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The easiest way to avoid scoping issues is to use iterators instead of loops: `[].forEach.call(someDOMcollection, function(node) {...})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Default values](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aparameter_default_values) is an ES6 extension and is currently only supported by Firefox.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/default_parameters

The simple solution here would be to store the value in a closure :

```
var self=this;
for(var b=0;b<this.someDOMcollection.length;b++){
    (function(pIndex){
        if(this.someDOMcollection[b].id==someCriteria){
            this.someDOMcollection[b].classList.add('flashMe');
            setTimeout(
                function(){
                    self.someDOMcollection[pIndex].classList.remove('flashMe');
                }
            ,1500);//end Timeout
            break;
        }//if
    })(b);
}//b
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you! It works, and extra thank you for pointers to useful docs.

Answer (score 1):

`function(pIndex=b){` is not valid JavaScript (yet). Use a Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE), instead:

```
(function(pIndex){ // Accept a parameter, named `pIndex`.
    setTimeout(function(){
        self.someDOMcollection[pIndex].classList.remove('flashMe');
    }, 1500);
})(b); // Pass `b` to the inner function.
```